# Swiper slider extension dose't work in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Swiper slider extension is not working in load page, it just works when I open inspect element in browsers.

my code is:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use romkaChev\yii2\swiper\Swiper;
?>
<article id="slider">
        <?php
        $item[] = ['<img src="/files/upload/slider/1.jpg" width="100%">',
                    '<img src="/files/upload/slider/2.jpg" width="100%">'
                   ]
        echo Swiper::widget([
            'items' => $item,
            'behaviours' => [
                Swiper::BEHAVIOUR_NEXT_BUTTON,
                Swiper::BEHAVIOUR_PREV_BUTTON,
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                Swiper::OPTION_PAGINATION_CLICKABLE => true,
                Swiper::OPTION_EFFECT => Swiper::OPTION_FADE,
                Swiper::OPTION_LOOP => true,
                Swiper::OPTION_AUTOPLAY => 3000,
                Swiper::OPTION_SPEED => 1000,
            ]
        ]);
        ?>
</article>
```